# Migrating app from sencha touch to ionic. How I can restore the local data?

Tags: sqlite, sencha-touch, local-storage, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing a new version of an app already present in the apple store. The old app was developed (by another developer) in sencha touch 1 and store locally all data on a sqlite db, while the new ionic app store in the local storage.

My question is.. when I will publish the new app what happens to the local data? There is a way to save the data from the sqlite db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about ionic but basically this is how it works:

Local data belongs to an app. If you update the app, it will keep the data and you should be able to retrieve it.

But if you have to create an entirely new app because of iconic the data will be lost.

Comment: We want to update the app so that who has already bought will not pay another time. So I would like to read these data from the sqlite local db but I don't know how. Maybe placing an sqlite db in the same place? I have the code of the old app but I'm not able to find where is the db... some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You said that the old app is a sencha touch app. So you should take a look at all stores the app uses. It's typically in app/stores. These stores use proxies to store data. Take a look at these. Since it's an sencha app it's probably using some kind of phonegap plugin to address a sqllite db. This plugin might be wrapped in a proxy.